# Generate RSA Public Key in the server, send to Android, which in turn encrypts a message and sends it back to the server where it is decrypted

Tags: android, spring-boot, rsa

The following code is used to generate a 2048-bit RSA public/private Key. The public key is sent to android app, which is used to encrypt a message that is to be decrypted in the service end.

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        byte[] encoded = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

But using the private key, any decryption resulted in a bad padding exception.

To encrypt, the following code was used:

```
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pKey);
        encoded = cipher.doFinal(clearText.getBytes());
```

Comment: `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");`. Don't rely on defaults, instead *always* specify the full "<algorithm/mode/padding>" string. By using defaults you get provider-specific behavior that is inherently non-portable. It was a mistaken by the Java cryptography designers to even allow such behavior, and relying on it is a Java crypto anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if you notice, there are different patterns which are acceptable by android but not supported by java and vice versa. So which should be the appropriate pattern that is acceptable at both ends?

Comment: For any reasonably modern platform, "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding". For old platforms that can't support OAEP, then "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging in both the android and the service (Using Spring boot as backend) end, I noticed that the provider in android (some implementation of OpenSSLRSA..) and service (SunRSASign) end was different.

As I was already thinking of switching to Bouncy Castle, all I had to do was mention the Bouncy Castle provider for both the platforms and both encryption/decryption was successful.

Like this:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, "BC");

// OR 

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Incorrect! You do not need to specify a provider, and should *not* specify a provider, unless there is something about a specific provider that you really need (e.g. the provider works with special hardware). In your case you were relying on defaults and then groping around for a solution. You stumbled upon the fact that, by using the same provider, you end up with the same defaults. But it is the use of defaults that's the real mistake.